# How can I send a file with a Graphql Mutation in insomnia.rest?

Tags: graphql, file-transfer, graphene-python

I'm trying to upload an image with a graphql mutation to my server, how can I test this with insomnia.rest? the the Structured request for a Graphql Query doesn't show any field to add a file. Also, if this isn't posible with insomnia, what other alternative can I use to test something like this?

Comment: `apollo-upload-client` is a client alternative

Comment: where can I find examples of how to implement a client, I'm very new to react so I don't find their readme very clear

Answer (score 13):

You'll want to use the "Multipart" request type. Then add the following values:

- `operations`: The graphql mutation in the format that is sent in the request, which should look something like below. (You can get this by using the GraphQL request option and switching to multipart form and then moving the values around).

```
{
 "query":"mutation UploadFile($file: File!) {\n  addResearch(file: $file)\n}",
 "variables":{ "file": null},
 "operationName":"UploadFile"
}
```

- `map`: `{ "File": ["variables.file"] }`
- `File`: The file to upload. Click the dropdown on right beside the value input and choose "File" so that you can select a file.

[image: Example image]

Comment: How about byte array? I am trying to pass in a byte array to a mutation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57446927/how-to-send-byte-array-to-graphql-mutation

Comment: Do you just have the array that you need to pass in? Or is it a blob or something?

Comment: It is a blob I want to pass in.

Comment: @SimplyComplexable: (newbie here)I dont get it, can u please provide images?

Comment: @Sushilzzz I just edited the example with an image. The image is a little different but should illustrate what what you're trying to do.

Comment: @SimplyComplexable an image different than the example is more confusing