# How to send byte array (Blob) to GraphQL mutation

Tags: graphql, insomnia, graphql-mutation, graphql-playground

We have a GraphQL mutation with a byte array (Blob) field. How can I use tools like Insomnia or GraphQL playground to send byte array data to test the API?

```
mutation {
  saveSomething(something: {
    contentByteArray: [97, 110, 103, 101, 108, 111]
  }) {
    content
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send data like that, however I understand that GraphQL sends a **List** of bytes rather than an array. In C# such a field (I'm uploading a photo) would be described as

```C#
Field<ListGraphType<ByteGraphType>>("photo");
```

and would need to be converted back into an array in order to be saved to the database
e.g.

```C#
IDictionary<string, object> dicPlayer = (IDictionary<string, object>)context.Arguments["input"];
...

if (dicPlayer.ContainsKey("photo")) {
    if (dicPlayer["photo"] == null) {
        playerInput.Photo = null;
    } else {
        List<byte> lstB = new List<byte>();
        foreach (var objB in (List<object>)dicPlayer["photo"]) {
            byte b = (byte)objB;
            lstB.Add(b);
        }
        byte[] arrB = lstB.ToArray();
        playerInput.Photo = arrB;
    }
}
```